# SSAS - Explore data - Missing Tabs

Tags: sql-server, ssas, pivot-table, ssas-2012

SSAS - Explore Data

[image]

I want to explore data of the data source view in SSAS; however, table view is the only option. Book MS Data Mining with MS SQL Server 2008 suggests more options as in the picture above.

Currently, I use SQL Server 2012 (multidimensional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to browse the cube in Management Studio or SQL Server Data Tools?  Unfortunately, the PivotTable browser was removed from those tools in SQL Server 2012. The PivotTable was based on Office Web Controls, which were deprecated.  The recommendation now is to use Excel. If you have Excel installed on your dev machine, you can launch it from SQL Server Data Tools, saving you a few steps (connection is setup for you automatically).

Comment: I use SQL Server Data Tools. I have Excel 2007 on my machine. I fail to find how to launch Excel from SQL Server Data tools. Subquestion: my data set is more than 1 million rows and excel handles up to a million.

Comment: Yea, this is really a step backwards. Sometimes there's a need to view the SSAS data before you cube it with the Chart tab for example--which is also missing. Now, that's impossible because the tables don't transfer directly for viewing from SSAS to Excel.